# Subfigures wrong alignment

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I am trying to align subfigures like this:

```
1 2
3 4
```

However, my figures are aligned this way:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I chose to resize the image because I thought it was caused by the image sizes.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{sectsty}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[style = apa6, 
sortcites=true,
sorting=nyt,
autocite=inline,
giveninits=true,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referencestest.bib}



\usepackage{fullpage}

\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

\makeindex


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}



\chapterfont{\centering}

\pagebreak
\setcounter{page}{3}




\tableofcontents{}


\chapter{Introduction}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagebreak


\section{Lorem}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\section{Ipsum}


\section{Lorem2}


\chapter{Ipsum2}

\section{Lorem3}

\section{Ipsum3}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \caption[My caption]{Mycaption}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Image 0.PNG}
            
        \end{center}
        \label{fig:GAQ}
    \end{subfigure}
        
\hfill

    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Image 1.PNG}
            
        \end{center}
        \label{fig:GNQ}
    \end{subfigure}\\

    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}%{\linewidth}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Image 2.png}
            
        \end{center}
        \label{fig:CDPD}
    \end{subfigure}

\hfill

    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Image 3.png}
            
        \end{center}
        \label{fig:CDPD}

    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\section{Lorem4}




\end{document}
```

Could you tell me what's wrong with my code?

A couple of days ago I found a page on this site where someone explained how to do it with a few images (6 or more). I didn't find it back.

Comment: Remove the blank lines around `\hfill`. Besides, you should use `\centering` rather than the `center` environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid blank lines when using subfigures. You can remove the `\hfill`s if you want your graphics centered. Also note that your labels should be unique.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \caption[My caption]{Mycaption}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:GAQ_1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:GNQ_2}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}%{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:CDPD_1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:CDPD_2}
    \end{subfigure}  
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]